# Eclipse says build finish but exe is not there

Tags: c++, eclipse, build

I am trying to write a "hello world" program with C++ in eclipse. I have choosen "microsoft visual c++" as tool chain, while starting a new project.

Also I added path of cl.exe to windows' path variable.

Now, I can build the code and I can take "Build Finished" message from eclipse but exe file is not in debug folder.

Output of the program is below:

> 15:08:52 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project helloWorld ****
>
> Info: Internal Builder is used for build
>
> cl /c /EHs /MD /Zi /nologo "/Fosrc\helloWorld.obj" "..\src\helloWorld.cpp"
>
> 15:08:52 Build Finished (took 174ms)

Answer (score 0):

You are compiling the source file, but not linking it. The `/c` option tells VC++ to skip the linking phase ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8we9bhf4(v=vs.71).aspx ) , which would turn your `.obj` file into an executable `.exe`.

Check your compiler settings and remove `/c` from the options, or explicitly call `LINK` as shown in the msdn link:

`LINK firsti.obj second.obj third.obj /OUT:filename.exe`

(Also, the `/Fo` switch should be outside the double quotes and separated  by a space.)

Comment: I have removed /c but same thing happened. Only output changed: cl /EHs /MD /Zi /nologo "/Fosrc\\MSCompileBoost2.obj" "..\\src\\MSCompileBoost2.cpp"

Comment: @Yavuz: Okay, maybe the `/c` actually should be there (i.e. eclipse would actually link later?), but there's something wrong with the `/Fo` switch, it should look like `... /nologo /Fo "src/MSCompileBoost2.obj"`, NOT like `... /nologo "/Fosrc/MSCompileBoost2.obj"`. Put the `/c` back in for now, and fix the `/Fo` problem first.

Comment: I can't find anything abaout /Fo option in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem when trying to configure a project to compile with MSVS 2003 (VC7) and I found using ProMon that CL.exe could not find a dll - adding the location to the PATH environment variable solved it.

See my full blog post here:
http://dandar3.blogspot.com/2013/06/eclipse-cdt-and-microsoft-visual-c.html